# Comments are cloned to red error message box thingy

Tags: bug, comments

[image: Sad of you not seeing this image. :(]

I clicked on `add / show N more comment`, afterwards something inside me provoked to refresh the page. Just before the page is reloaded this abomination showed up, which I frantically took a screenshot just like someone seeing Bigfoot.

I'm worried.

Really, this is something I don't want children to be seeing.

---

**UPDATE:**

> Do you mean you refreshed the page while the comment list was being loaded? It is possible this is a side-effect of the AJAX request returning failure because of the reload. Looks like an edge case if it only occurs in this situation, though. –  [Frédéric Hamidi](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/263081/comments-are-cloned-to-red-error-message-box-thingy#comment55801_263081)

Ah yes, I remember it now. The slow loading of the comments is why I reloaded the page.

> Looks like an edge case if it only occurs in this situation, though.

As a fellow programmer, I agree. Still *let's better be careful we don't want to scare the children*.

I understand this is [low-priority](/questions/tagged/low-priority) [edge-case](/questions/tagged/edge-case), so no pressure SE team!

Comment: Do you mean you refreshed the page while the comment list was being loaded? It is possible this is a side-effect of the AJAX request returning failure because of the reload. Looks like an edge case if it only occurs in this situation, though.